# Java Interface Code is Wrong?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on an assignment about java interface and I'm in the last 2 steps stuck there without knowing the exact problem here is the code I wrote

```
  @Override     
  public boolean isNonDescending() {            
    double smallestElement = data[0];       
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length;) {     
      if (data[i] >= smallestElement) {     
        i++;        
      }     
    }   
    return true;        
  }
```

but when I submit my work to WebCat, it says this specific method is not working as it suppose to do, the main thing it should do is:

• **isNonDescending**: Returns a boolean value indicating whether the set of elements
is organized from smallest to largest (with equal elements being adjacent). Put
another way, a set of elements is nondescending if there is no smaller element that
comes after a larger element. For example, (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5) is nondescending while
(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5) is not, because a smaller element (1) came after a larger element (3).

the other method which are mentioned **smallestElement** in the method **IsNonDescending** if you need it:

```
  @Override     
  public double smallestElement() {     
    double minElement = data[0];    
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {     
      if (data[i] < minElement) {   
        minElement = data[i];   
      }     
    }       
    return minElement;      
  }
```

My question is where is the line with a wrong code or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you check, in your head, that the array is ascending? You check that every element is greater or equal to the previous one, right? Then do that also in your code. Note that it would be much clearer if the method was named `isAscending()`, rather than `isNonDescending()`.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do in `isNonDescending` You are supposed to check if there are any instances in which the next element is bigger than the current element, and if yes, then return true, else if no such was found then return false

Comment: The method in your first example always returns `true`. You should add a `else`case witch returns `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine I run your `isNonDescending` method on the following array : `[ 1,2,0]`

The `if` test is going to be wrong for the first element, so `i` will never be incremented and you will have an infinite loop. Plus, you never return false in your method. You should do this to fix it :

```
@Override     
public boolean isNonDescending() {       
   // starting at 1 since we will be looking at data[i-1], which
   // must start at 0. Alternatively, you can write 
   // for (int i=0 ; i < data.length - 1 ; i++) and work with data[i+1]  
   for (int i = 1 ; i < data.length ; i++)     
      if (data[i] > data[i-1]) return true;   
   return false;        
}
```

Comment: This doesnt deliver the correct result for {3,2,1,2}. It returns false, even though {3,2,1,2} is not a descending ordered array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNonDescending() {            
  for (int i = 1; i < data.length-1; i++) {     
    if (data[i-1] > data[i]) {     
      return false;
    }     
  }   
  return true;        
}
```

but I would name it isAscending(), nonDescending() doesn't describe your example correctly.

Comment: *Ascending* is **not** the contrary of *non descending*. Plus, your inequality is in the wrong way.

Comment: I didn't say it was. I was writing code to pass the OP's examples not implementing the name of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@Override
    public static boolean isNonDescending() {
        boolean success = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            if (data[i - 1] > data[i]) {
                success = false;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: `data.length - 1` should be `data.length`. That apart, it works, however you loop through the entire array whereas you can return at the first failed test. If you do want a single `return` statement, add use `i < data.length && success`